# System.InvalidOperationException: Nullable object must have a value. can't get SelectList count

Tags: asp.net-core, selectlist

I'm trying to get the count of a SelectList.  Lets name this SelectList **"Sessions"**.  When trying to use Sessions.Count(), the error **"System.InvalidOperationException: Nullable object must have a value"** happens.  Inspecting the Items list shows 1000s of items.  Why is this throwing this error?  What needs to happen to get it to stop?

Comment: Could you please share your relevant code snippet in order to reproduce your issue.